# React Storing data for complicated processing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am somewhat new to ReactJS.

I want to store data for complicated computations in ReactJS. Since the `setState` is asynchronous, I cannot be bothered to store all the required data inside `state` as it would be next to impossible to do what I want.

I was thinking of doing the following: store the needed variables inside an object inside the state itself. E.g the state defined in the constructor is the following object

```
constructor(props){
    this.state = { complicated_storage: { x : 123, y : 324 } }
}
```

This way I can manipulate `this.state.compicated_storage.x` or `this.state.compicated_storage.y`, and do stuff like `this.state.compicated_storage.x = 4` without worrying about asynchronous behavior.

Is this a bad way of doing stuff in ReactJS. I noticed that with this you can bypass the entire `setState` mechanism, and just store all my variables inside the object within the `state`.

Thank You

Comment: *Since the setState is asynchronous, I cannot be bothered to store all the required data inside state as it would be next to impossible to do what I want.* Those two sentences don't seem to have anything to do with each other. Asynchronity can easily be worked with, and doesn't interfere with the data structure of state.

Comment: @Snow Thank You for your comment. Let's say that I needed to do something like x = 5 and x-=10 sequentially. If I do `setState({x:5}); setState({x: this.state.x - 10})` then that would lead to trouble. I know I can do `setState({x:5}, ()=>{setState{x: this.state.x - 10}})` instead, but this seems like an unnecessary hassle to newBie like me. Like I mentioned in my reply to @John Smith, I did was not sure whether performing an assignment on the class field like `this.x = 5` would cause an error. If I can just do that then this issue will be cleared up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a bad way of doing stuff in ReactJS. I noticed that with this you can bypass the entire setState mechanism, and just store all my variables inside the object within the state.

The entire purpose of state is re-rendering components whenever it changes. If you modify it directly, such as `state.someVariable = 2`, React will not know about your change, and it will not rerender your components after the change (however, the change will be reflected if something else later causes a rerender).

If you need a change to some data trigger a rerender and update the view, use state together with `setState`.

If not, you can simply use a class field, rather than store it inside state.

Besides, I'm not sure in what way asynchrony you think will impede your goals, so perhaps you should be clearer there. State being asynchronous just means that changes to state are made "a little later" after the function is called (it's a whole other topic), so React can batch updates for performance reasons.

Last but not least, you should look into hooks (useState), instead of using class components.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I was under the notion that changing the class field like `this.x = 5` would trigger an error. Is that not the case? I just wanted to change variables without re-rendering everything.

Comment: @SrijanJoshi No, it wouldn't cause an error, and I suggest you check such a simple thing yourself. It just won't cause an immediate rerender, but the change will be reflected if some rerender happens later for whatever reason. I suggest you keep the things you don't need to cause a rerender in class fields, then use `this.forceUpdate()` to trigger a rerender whenver you need. Inside a function component, you can just have a redundant bool useState changing between true/false to trigger rerenders.

Comment: Great! I did check myself by performing `this.x = 5`. However, I was not sure if I was just being lucky with the variable changing.
I remember playing around with `this.state.x = 5`. However, the change was happening sometimes, and not happening at other times (it was random). I was worried if this was the same behavior for class fields.
Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The change in the UI was not random, it was reflected once something else (after your `state.x = 5`) called `setState` to update the UI. Again, technically (though its a misuse of state), you can make `state.x = 5` and similar direct changes to the state as many times as you like (and indeed `console.log` will reflect it), but the browser UI will update only after 'something' triggers a rerender, be it some unrelated `setState`, different props being passed in, or `forceUpdate`.

Comment: Nice Technical Details. It would have been very difficult to find this info by searching looking it up on the internet. I googled a lot about the behavior of state and I could not confirm what was actually going on behind the scenes.